# Facebook FB.Init Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, x-frame-options

Following the Facebook instructions, FB.Init in Chrome produces

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?...' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

However, there are no frames on the page. IE, strangely enough, seems happy with the call.

Based on a stackoverflow suggestion, I added

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

to `system.webServer`

to no avail.

So something else is happening here. There seems to be a lot questions on SO relating to this problem, but with no clear solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>

<script>
    // -----------------------------
    var FBinitialised = false;

     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<MY_APP_ID>',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true, 
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });

        console.log( 'after FB.init');

        FB.getLoginStatus( function( response){
            FBinitialised = true;
            console.log( 'FBinitialised');
        });
    };

    // ---------------------------------
    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    console.log( 'End of script');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: The SDK sometimes creates iframe elements itself. Is anything of what you are trying to achieve here not working? If that is not the case, then simply ignore these errors.

Comment: Thanks but `FBinitialised` never gets set in Chrome, but is in IE.

Answer (score 1):

After much boredom, it appears that Chrome and FF on my machine have been corrupted, perhaps by Kaspersky script injection. Re-installing W10 has solved the problem. Apologies.